# How to update existing model with new training data in TFlearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, text-classification, tflearn

I'm new for Tensorflow , I'm using This tutorial- https://sourcedexter.com/tensorflow-text-classification-python/ for text classification build model.

i'm saving the model using below code.

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('./model.tflearn',)
```

This gives below files.

```
model.tflearn.data-00000-of-00001
model.tflearn.index
model.tflearn.meta
tflearn_logs folder
```

But when i save Existing model(with new Training dataset). i'm getting prediction value only for new trained datas not for existing datas. How to append new train dataset in existing save model.

Thanks.

Comment: if anyone know the answer ,please  suggest me...Thanks...